# ng2-material: "zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: TypeError: core_1.NgModule is not a function"

Tags: angular, angular2-material

I am trying to run basic Angular2 Application with Angular2-material, However getting the following error.

**zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: TypeError: core_1.NgModule is not a function**

[image: Error Screenshot]

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular2-material/card';
import { MdButton } from '@angular2-material/button';

    @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
      directives: [
        MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES,
        MdButton,
      ],

   })
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

I have followed all the steps shown [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into the error created by the changes in RC5.  Here is a guide that explains how to change your configuration to support RC5 and NgModule in the bootstrapping of the application:
https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/08/13/updating-your-angular-2-app-from-rc4-to-rc5-a-practical-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Adding an app module with NgModule was added in RC5.  You might try looking at your pacakage.json to see if you are on RC4.

You are most likely on rc4 in your package.json for angular libraries but a dependency is built on RC5.  I would try upgrading to Rc5.

You can follow the angular upgrade rc4 to rc5 docs here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html